# Google Chrome is installed but Ubuntu Software Centre says it's not

Tags: 12.04, software-center, google-chrome, downloads

Ubuntu 12.04.

When I was on Ubuntu 11.10 and 11.04, Google Chrome was available to download from the Software Centre. Now I'm on 12.04 and the Software Centre is saying Chrome is NOT downloaded and it is not available to download.

Why doesn't it say that it is downloaded?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open your update manager and click at settings.Then you will directs to a window and in that windows choose Other software TAB.

Make sure that you have checked the following (in image )sources , If you done already then you worth a try with `sudo apt-get update`.

[image]

Comment: How can I get to that step? (As shown in the picture)

Comment: oh sorry @nerof61 . I will update the answer.

Comment: That's ok. I don't mind.

Comment: They are all ticked. And it worked. Thanks very much!!! (I've got 2 wait to accept your answer.)